# Android dynamic table creation with ImageView and TextView design with date at parent right

Tags: android, dynamic, alignment

[I am not able to put two textview's to the right of ImageView and aligning the date to parent right is also getting difficult for me in dynamic creation. someone who have knowledge on this please help me. Design should be DYNAMIC.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bXY0V.png)

```
    tl = (TableLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);

       TableRow row2 = new TableRow(getContext());
                    row2.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(200, 230, 280));


                    TableLayout posterInfoTable = new TableLayout(getContext());
                    posterInfoTable.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.whitegrey);
                    posterInfoTable.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 250));

                    TableRow posterNameRow = new TableRow(getContext());
                    TableLayout.LayoutParams lp = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                    lp.setMargins(0, 0, 30, 0);
                    posterNameRow.setHorizontalGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
                    posterNameRow.setLayoutParams(lp);

                    ImageView posterImage = new ImageView(getContext());
                    posterImage.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                    posterImage.setMaxHeight(100);
                    posterImage.setMaxWidth(100);
                    Picasso.with(getContext())

                            .load(R.drawable.dummyimage2)
                            .placeholder(R.drawable.dummyimage2)
                            .error(R.drawable.dummyimage2)
                            .transform(new RoundedTransformation(50, 4))
                            .resizeDimen(R.dimen.list_detail_image_size, R.dimen.list_detail_image_size)
                            .centerCrop()
                            .into(posterImage);
                    posterNameRow.addView(posterImage);

                    final TableRow nameRow = new TableRow(getContext());
                    nameRow.setPadding(40, 0, 0, 0);
                    nameRow.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(250, 100));
                    nameRow.setTag(db_id);

                    TextView posterName = new TextView(getContext());
                    posterName.setText(postman);
                    posterName.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                    posterName.setTextSize(18);
                    posterName.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
                    posterName.setWidth(240);
                    // posterName.text
                    posterNameRow.addView(posterName);

                    TextView dateview = new TextView(getContext());
                    dateview.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT))
                    dateview.setText(date);
                    dateview.setPadding(50, 0, 0, 5);
                    dateview.setTextColor(Color.DKGRAY);
                    dateview.setTextSize(10);
                    dateview.setWidth(300);
                    dateview.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
                    nameRow.addView(dateview);

                    posterInfoTable.addView(posterNameRow);
                    posterInfoTable.addView(nameRow);

                    //  posterInfoTable.addView(dateRow);

                    row2.addView(posterInfoTable, new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 200));
                    //   row2.addView(dateview);


                    tl.addView(row2, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 200));
```

Answer (score 0):

you do not need to create all views dynamically. Create XML with your item-layout. try this:

```
void addNewRow(YourData data) { 
    View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.your_item, null);
    RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) v; //or other...
    TextView textView1 = (TextView) rl.findViewById(R.id.textV1);
    ImageView imageView1 = (ImageView) rl.findViewById(R.id.imageV1);
    textView1.setText(data.name);
    imageView.setImageResource(data.imageRes);
    tableLayout.addView(rl);
}
```